# TS import from ES6 file

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm using Webpack in an ES6 project. I am attempting to enable TypeScript without converting all files to .ts. However TS does not recognize any of my ES6 modules. Example:

I have a .js file which uses ES6 module syntax:

```
export default "foo";
```

In a .ts file I want to import "foo":

```
import foo from "./foo";
```

However TypeScript tells me that it `Cannot find module "./foo"`.

Is there any way to make TS understand that these modules exist without writing `d.ts` files for all of them (not really possible) or convert *everything* to .ts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have a .js file which uses ES6 module syntax:

Add `allowJs` to your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: What's up with all the roses? :)

Comment: `What's up with all the roses` just sharing the love 